# Ударение в словах "cоздал" и "воссоздал"

Tags: егэ, орфоэпия

Говорят, в первом случае возможны два варианта ударения, во втором - только один: воссоздАл. Так ли это?

Comment: Говорят словари?

Answer (score 2):

Создать, **-а**м, **-а**шь, -**а**ст, -адим, -ад**и**те, -ад**у**т; прош. с**о**зд**а**л, создал**а**, с**о**зд**а**ло

воссозд**а**ть, -**а**м, -**а**шь, -**а**ст, -ад**и**м, -ад**и**те, -ад**у**т; прош. -**а**л, -ал**а** , -**а**ло

> См.: Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
>   Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.

Однако строго-нормативным является: созд**а**ть, созд**а**м, созд**а**шь,создад**и**те, создад**у**т; с**о**здал, создал**а**, с**о**здало,с**о**здали

> См.:  Русское словесное ударение.Словарь нарицательных имён.
>   Автор М. В. Зарва.
>   Печатное издание М.: ЭНАС, 2001.

Comment: Серж, разве "сОздать" правильно?

Comment: Матвей,  я случайно не ту гласную выделил. Сейчас все исправил.

Answer (score 0):

[Правильно говорят](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=*%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x).

---

Поясните, в чем именно вопрос-то?

Касательно "строгой нормативности". Словарь Зарвы более консервативен, чем нормативен. Он даже в случае двух равноправных вариантов дает всегда только один. Это не строгая нормативность, это просто принцип построения словаря. В данном случае выбран более старый вариант. Но можно с достаточной долей уверенности прогнозировать, что в не столь отдаленном будущем он устареет и уступит место новому.